# Issues in RESTFul Webservice annotation

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, classpath, jersey

I am trying to write a RESTFul Webservice using Jersey.

```
package sample.hello.resources;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloResource  {   
    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey";
    }
}
```

My Eclipse give error for all the annotations - `@Path, (Path cannot be resolved to a type)`

Do I need to include any other libraries or configure the projects in Eclipse?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that `Path` annotation exists in `jersey-core` library. I think you should include that library in your project

Comment: Jersey-core library is available in lib directory.

Comment: There is no other necessary library, please check if you add the library to classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Add the **javax.ws.rs.jar** and import :

```
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
```

Is need to help!